# What are the most useful axes methods in creating XPath expressions for Selenium web automation?

Tags: selenium, ui-testing

I am very new to Selenium, and I have just learnt about XPath axes methods. I am bit confused to use those methods in creating XPath expressions.

What are the most useful axes methods with examples?

Axes methods:

```
1. Ancestor
2. Parent
3. Child
4. Following-sibling
5. Preceding-sibling
6. Following
7. Preceding
8. Descendant, etc.
```

Comment: Check http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/xpath-tutorial-for-selenium and https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question. All the access methods have their own purpose. Until the web page we inspect has very complicated structure we will not look into these access methods.

However even in typical situations we first try to use simple solutions, in my case I first try to solve my problem with the following, proceeding methods, even in typical situations, and if it still goes as worst scenario I will look into even more remaining advanced methods.

Finally I try to write the XPath expression as small as possible.

Comment: Thank you raja..! Is is possible to write an xpath for an element in a web table without using indices. I have tried this but couldn't and my intention is to avoid using indices in xpath creation. If it is possible can you explain me with an example. Thanks again

Comment: Ya sure, can you give a scenario.
 I can explain you on your scenario

Comment: Consider a scenario where i have only a base parent and child div tags
`<div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
.
.
.
300 times
</div>`

My intension is to select only the 150th occurrence.
When we are finding something in DOM using xpath only the 1st occurrence will be returned by default
So, in order get the exact value we have to use indices.
For the tags which i have given inorder to find the 150th occurrence. i will write xpath as follows:
`(//div/div)[150]`

So, indices are good to use for better results